# ./src/App.js Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I can't figure it out why doesn't work. I have uninstalled the react-router-dom package and reinstalled it, but I always have the same error.

The error I'm getting: **./src/App.js
Attempted import error: 'Switch' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.**

This is my code.
I hope that someone could give me a hand,
Thanks in advance

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import NavBar from '../src/Components/UI/NavBar/NavBar';
import Footer from '../src/Components/UI/Footer/Footer';
import Home from './Components/Views/Home/Home';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <NavBar/>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/">
          <Home/>
        </Route> 
      </Switch>
      <Footer/>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and took me forever.
but mainly as you have asked recently the **React-router-dom has been updated** and they have removed **Switch** So try installing below code again. its version 5.

```html
npm install react-router-dom@5
```

Answer (score 0):

If you accidentally updated `react-router-dom` to version 6 it no longer exports a `Switch` component. It was replaced by a `Routes` component that ***must*** directly wrap/render the `Route` components.

1. Swap the `Switch` for the `Routes` component.

   ```
   import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
   ...

   function App() {
     return (
       <Router>
         <NavBar/>
         <Routes>
           <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
         </Routes>
         <Footer/>
       </Router>
     );
   }
   ```

   Follow the [Upgrading from v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) to migrate your project from v5 to v6 across your app as there were quite a few breaking component API changes.
2. Revert back to `react-router-dom` v5.

   - Run `npm un -s react-router-dom`
   - Run `npm i -s react-router-dom@5.3.0`

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem. I had version 6 installed. Then I have found out that `Switch` was replaced by `Routes`. But changing to Routes was messing with my front-end. So I uninstall the version and went back to previous version by these commands:

> npm uninstall react-router-dom

> npm install react-router-dom@5.2.0

This has solved my problem with 'Switch is not exported error'.