# Can't get react-router-dom to work (seeing blank page)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This is my `App` component that has 3 child components: `Home`, `Contact` and `Procedures`. I'm trying to make each child component into its own url route.

However right now I'm just seeing a blank page

FYI- I'm using react-router-dom@6.0.2

```
import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import Home from './Home.js'
import Contact from './Contact.js'
import Procedures from './Procedures.js'

import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/procedures" component={Procedures} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please verify your `react-router-dom` version. From the project directory run `npm list react-router-dom`. There were significant changes between v5 and v6, and you're mixing the `Route` syntax between them.

Comment: react-router-dom@6.0.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70266560/src-app-js-attempted-import-error-switch-is-not-exported-from-react-router/70266648#70266648 Which version do you want to use?

Comment: how would this work if I keep version 6?

Comment: Render the routed components on the `element` prop as JSX instead of a reference to the component, i.e. `<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />`. The `exact` prop is not also no longer used as all routes are *always* exactly matched in RRDv6.

Comment: that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In react-router-dom version 6 you should use element instead of component, also be sure to reference the element you want to render as JSX. By the way, there is no longer any "exact" attribute.

Should look like this on your code:

```
<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
```